# WPF Combobox object selection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have two classes:

```
  class Customer
  {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PriceGroup priceGroup {get; set}
  }

  class PriceGroup
  {
        public int PriceGroupId {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public override string ToString() {return name;}
  }
```

I have also a dataset of PriceGroup objects:

```
DataSet<PriceGroup> priceGroups;
```

It contains few elements.

I need to have the ability to select PriceGroup in Combobox and set it up in Customer.priceGroup member.

At the moment I'm able to display priceGroups items in Combobox without any problem with following code:

```
Combobox.ItemsSource = priceGroups;
```

But I have no idea how to handle selection.
I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
  <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxPriceGroup" 
            Text="{Binding priceGroup}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedValuePath="PriceGroup"
            SelectedValue="{Binding priceGroup}"/>
```

Do you have any idea how should I set up ComboBox properties, so it would update Customer.priceGroup member when Combobox selection changes?

Comment: Get rid of the binding on `Text`. What you have should be fine otherwise, assuming `priceGroup` actually exists, and depending on where it's defined -- although of course your classes should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Why don't you use SelectionChanged event handler?

Comment: Is a `Customer` the `DataContext`?

Comment: Why do you use SelectedValuePath, while you also use a binding for SelectedValue? Also, what exactly are you trying to refer to with the SelectedValuePath property?

Comment: Yeah, priceGroup exists. Customer exists in DataContext as well.
Thanks for the advice. I'll try it.

Comment: @elgonzo is correct, you must also remove `SelectedValuePath="PriceGroup"`. That attribute will cause the ComboBox to try to set `SelectedValue` to that property of the selected `PriceGroup` instance -- but `PriceGroup` doesn't have a `PriceGroup` property. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, sorry, i think i got the wording wrong in my last comment. It indeed sounds like i was suggesting that SelectedValuePath is not to be used together with SelectedValue. Usually SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue are used in conjunction. My intention was rather to invite Marcin to double-check and verify his assumptions about the mechanism behind SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue.

Comment: @elgonzo Sorry, shouldn't have put words in your mouth! But the way he had it wasn't going to work, and you called attention to the issue where I missed it. I'm pretty sure he's populating the combo with `PriceGroup` instances.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, no need to apologize. It's me who didn't really pay attention when i wrote my comment. And the way i wrote it really heavily encourages such an interpretation. :)